# Email from flow is not triggered when user who created it gets deactivated

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

What can I possibly do?

Emails stopped working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. Flows are stored as part of the user who created them, and by default they run under the credentials of the user as well. First, I would immediately contact your SharePoint admins and verify that the Flow has been shared with another user and get ownership transferred, as the flow itself could get deleted.

Because of the issue you raised, many shops set up a "service account", and use this service account to build flows and/or use it as the account for connections such as email.

Service account = an account where the password doesn't expire.

Comment: if i have understood well, first i need to log in with the other person's account (what if it was deleted?) then share it with me, then I share it with a service account that never expires?

Comment: Two strategies: 1) what you described. Log in as that user, share it out with yourself and/or service account. Or 2) log in as that user, export it, and then while logged in as yourself or service account, import it, which creates a separate copy of the flow, where you (or the service account) is the full owner.

Comment: If the account was deleted, and if the flow was never shared with anyone else prior that the account being deleted, then the flow is gone.

Comment: I suppose that the service account must have a license or not? If I need to edit the flow, do I do it while logged with the service account?

Comment: Yes, that account would need a license. Some orgs use the service account to build flows and powerapps, so it is that service account that completely owns the flow/powerapp. Other orgs use the service account for the connections, so that the emails are coming from the service account rather than as the user who created the flow. In any case, remember that if a user builds a flow, doesn't share it, and then that user account is deleted, the flow is also deleted.